# htacces & sub-directories

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, .htaccess, web-hosting

How could I give different access to sub-directories?

The first problem is: I must let the programmers modify the htaccess files, but not the access control.

I have access only to htaccess directives for once, not to the httpd.conf of Apache.
And here are my folders:

```
~/www/
~/beta/ -> group betatesters developers
~/dev/ -> group developers
```

I would like to have only one .htaccess located in the root directory (developers don't have access there).

```
~/.htaccess
~/htpassd
~/htgroup
```

.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /home123/user321/htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /home123/user321/htgroup
<FilesMatch "beta">
    Require group betatesters developers
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "dev">
    Require group developers
</FilesMatch>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can set in the Apache conf what parameters are fair game to be changed in a `.htaccess` file.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

In your specific example, you don't want the `AuthConfig` settings to be overidable.  You can do that either by not listing AuthConfig with the `AllowOveride` directive. eg.

```
<Directory foo>
   AllowOveride Indexes <...>
</Directory>
```

Or explicitly declaring that `AuthConfig` is not modifiable.

```
<Directory foo>
   AllowOveride -AuthConfig <other options here>
</Directory>
```

Comment: it's not that I don't want  Authconfig to be overidable or not, it's that I want a different one for each. And in a perfect world it would not be in .htacces in each directory itself

Answer (score 1):

after you stated you DON'T have access to httpd.conf, Joshua Hoblitt answer only applies partially.

if it is possible for you to use another directory structure like

```
~/www
~/www/beta
~/www/dev
```

you could adapt Joshua's solution.

Comment: I don't understand how I could have the equivalent of a `<Directory>` for each... directory. Since my goal is to have different rules for each one.

Comment: sorry i missunderstood